# Elements nested in pos abs parent does not respect parents padding bottom

Tags: css, padding, absolute

So, having trouble with the content of my absolute positioned parent.
For some reason the padding is only applied to top, left and right. The bottom value does not have any effect.

Here's a demo:
http://jsbin.com/aWUQIgIw/1

```
fieldset .inner-fieldset {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question - and if you're referring to `div.inner-fieldset` it indeed does have padding on all four sides (Chrome 32, Windows 7).

Comment: @Natsu Yes indeed. It's `.inner-fieldset`. It's not working as expected in Firefox 26 in OSX (Safari and Chrome is fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent root container is positioned absolutely to the body with `overflow-y: scroll`. The padding *is* in the DIV but the content is overflowing the bottom. Overflow content is shown behind padding since it's "inside" the parent element.

The easiest fix is to convert padding to margin for the container, which will properly hide the content.

Edit: You mentioned the goal was to have spacing between the actual text content and the bottom of the window after scrolling:

You can't have an absolutely positioned div with overflow content apply padding to the bottom of the overflown content... so there's no other way. If it's the spacing you're after, something inside the positioned div needs a margin/padding-bottom

http://jsbin.com/aWUQIgIw/6/

Comment: Thanks! The problem wiht margin is that it creates a "border" around the content. The whole height is not utilized. It's actually meant for a form, but the form elements have been removed for this demo.

Comment: Then I don't understand the goal with padding if you *dont* want the border. Maybe you just want to add some spacing below the bottom of your content? If so just add a margin-bottom to the last element in the content or use a wrapper div inside the abs. pos. div

Comment: Absolutely, that's one way to do it. But to me that's a way around the problem. The solution to use if all other fail. But maybe there's no better way.

Comment: You can't have an absolutely positioned div with overflow content apply padding to the bottom of the overflown content... so there's no other way. If it's the spacing you're after, something *inside* the positioned div needs a margin/padding-bottom

Comment: If you'd care to edit your answer to reflect this last comment I'd gladly accept this as an answer! Thanks alot.

Comment: Updated the answer for both scenarios